# How to stop executing PHP script when 10 MB of data has been output

Tags: php, apache

I have an Apache server with an outbound transfer limit of 6 GB. In a PHP script I accidentally ran a loop that outputted an enormous amount of data and used almost all of my allocated bandwidth.

Is there a way I can limit each request to only output 10 MB of data and then either kill the process or let it run but don't output anything else, to avoid such problems in the future ?

Here's what a problematic request looks like in the log :

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.204 - - [16/Jan/2015:16:10:01 +0100] "GET /ebok/ebok.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5368709120 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
```

I tried with ini_set

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1M');
$a = array();
for($x=1; $x<1000; $x++) {
    array_push($a, array('imie'=>'Pablo'.$x, 'nazwisko'=>'picasso'.$x,     'adres'=>'nowowiejska'.$x));
}
print_r($a);
exit;
?>
```

and I get message:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1048576 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/public_html/bench.php on line 5
```

but in apache log it takes only 10KB

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.134 - - [16/Jan/2015:23:25:50 +0100] "GET /bench.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: [Duplicate question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/659711/configuration-for-maximum-response-size-for-apache) (from a different user though, no intentional cross-posting)

Comment: Yes, it is. You are confusing how much **memory** a script uses when it runs with the volume of output. And you asked how to restrict the output.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a couple of different sources of stuff that use your bandwidth. Text, such as javascript and php output, likely comprises a relatively small portion of your bandwidth. Images will take more space, and files like an ebook will take the most space per request.

There may be a setting you can apply to apache's httpd.conf file to limit the maximum size per request there. I couldn't find it in a couple minutes of googling but you may have some luck (or maybe someone here knows the actual command!)

You can also set ob_start() at the top of your script and take a look at your output buffer size before you endflush() it at the end of your script. If it is too big, you can truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try buffering you output and trimming it to desired size (10 MB) before actually sending it to the client.

This is kind of a workaround, but I think it could work:

```
<?php
//start buffering output
ob_start();

echo 'Hello'; //echo something, string is buffered now, nothing is sent
var_dump(strlen(ob_get_contents()); // this should print int(5), as 5 bytes are in the string echoed

//get the buffered output, flush output buffer and stop buffering
$output = ob_get_flush();

//echo first 10 milion bytes (10 MB) = send it to the client
echo substr($output, 0, 1e7);
```

For more info on output buffering, see [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) in PHP docs.